# CKEditor toolbar missing items such as styling

Tags: javascript, rubygems, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-5

The toolbar for my editor is missing options. For example, I am not able to create headers.

Ive tried multiple different configurations in the JS file, though the editor seems to not change.

[image: what my toolbar looks like now]

```
if (typeof(CKEDITOR) != 'undefined') {
  CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbar = [
        { name: 'document', items: [ 'Print' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language' ] },
        { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
        { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
        { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
        { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
        { name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] }
    ];
  };
}
```

I'm trying to have a full toolbar as I am creating a website with blog articles and need all of the possible styling options.

Comment: Not sure how you're handling assets, but if you're using the asset pipeline you might try `rake assets:clobber` and restarting your web server

Comment: @NMPennypacker that didnt change anything

Comment: Which package you use? Please open `ckeditor/build-config.js` and check which preset is assigned. If you have anything other than `full` then you need to go to https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/ and download a full package.

Comment: @NMPennypacker oh my god I feel like a complete idiot. Thank you.

Comment: @NMPennypacker place that as an answer so I can submit it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your configuration, but I'm guessing you have some stale assets sitting around. You may need to run `rake:assets:clobber`. After that you can restart your development server, refresh the page, and the assets should re-compile.